# Count all possible contiguous sub matices with exactly K 1's - Binary Matrix

Tags: algorithm

**The problem:**

Given a NxN 0-1 matrix and a number K, count all sub matrices (any size) with exactly K 1's.

Constrains:  2 <= N <= 600, 1<= K <= 6

**Example**

```
1 0 1
0 0 0
1 0 1

Count: 8
```

With memoization of the sums of all possible sub matrices my algorithm has complexity O(n^4). I tried to combine various solutions for different but similar problems with no luck. I can't think a better way to reduce the time complexity. Could be done in O(n^3)?

I have read the following:

[Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)

[Submatrix with maximum sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643908/getting-the-submatrix-with-maximum-sum)

[Minimum area submatrix with sum K](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639172/submatrix-with-sum-k)

[Minimal subrectangle with at least K 1's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630803/how-to-find-minimal-subrectangle-with-at-least-k-1s-in-a-0-1-matrix)

**This is a homework.**

Comment: I am searching 5 days and I just find a duplicate in related section: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321927/how-to-check-sums-of-all-possible-rectangles-of-array Should I delete the post?